# pandas value_counts in ray

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, ray

I am pretty new to Ray and trying to use it for some data analysis operations on very large datasets

Lets say I have data in the following format

| score_A | score_B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 5 | 11 |

`pd["score_A"].value_counts()` will yield the answer

| Value | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |

How can I parallelize this computation using [ray](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/) for all columns in my dataframe?

I could find no documentation for any API similar to `value_counts` out of the box in the [ray data API](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/data/data.html)

Should I use somekind of custom aggregator?